# How to make same height on the links inside the child DIVs?

Tags: html, css, height

I am trying to make a PREV and NEXT section on the website. For that I tool one parent DIV and two child DIVs, inside the child DIVs there are links to the previous and next articles. But the issue that, height of the links is not the same. I want to make them same.

The HTML & CSS code is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style type="text/css">
.prev1{
    padding-right: 4px;
    text-align: left;
}
.next1{
    padding-left: 8px;
    text-align: right;
}
.i3nextprev a, .i3nextprev a:visited{
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 95%;
        font-weight: 700;
        background-color: #006969;
        DISPLAY: block;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<h1>Article</h1>
<div class="w3-row i3nextprev">
    <div class="w3-half prev1">
        <a href="#">Python program for various list operations</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-half next1">
        <a href="#">Extract Even and odd number from a given list in Python</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The output is this:**

[Two rectangular elements, on the first one "<Python program for various list operations" and on the second one "Extract Even and odd numbers from a list in Python"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3jKL.png)

Comment: The output described doesn't seem to match the output of the code snippet.  Can you update it to demonstrate?  (The CSS appears to be broken, which means either (1) it's also broken in your code or (2) this isn't the actual code you're asking about.)

Comment: @David for the reference can I send a live URL (will remove once the task is done)?

Comment: It's always better to post your code here, but did you consider adding fixed specific height and width to each?

Comment: @SUDHIRSHARMA: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour the parent DIV is using w3-row and child div having w3-half (which are standard CSS for the part of w3.css. I am updating the code with it.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Kindly check I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want? I've added `height:45px;` on `.i3nextprev a, .i3nextprev a:visited`.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />
            <style type="text/css">
                .prev1 {
                    padding-right: 4px;
                    text-align: left;
                }
                .next1 {
                    padding-left: 8px;
                    text-align: right;
                }

                .i3nextprev a,
                .i3nextprev a:visited {
                    height: 45px;
                    color: #fff;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    font-size: 95%;
                    font-weight: 700;
                    background-color: #006969;
                    display: block;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <h1>Article</h1>
        <div class="w3-row i3nextprev">
            <div class="w3-half prev1">
                <a href="#">Python program for various list operations</a>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-half next1">
                <a href="#">Extract Even and odd number from a given list in Python</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution may fail, if the anchor text is long i.e., in 3-4 rows. I need something which is related to the height of either child DIV.

Comment: @SUDHIRSHARMA `height:100%` is more suitable but each `<div>` will have each its own height.

Comment: DIVs are using their standard height i.e., an `auto` cannot make the changes in the CSS `w3-half` as it was using thousand of pages for various purpose. Anything that can be done with `prev1` and `next1` classes to maintain the height if anchor text of either DIV is long.